# log4j.configurationFile System Property

Tags: log4j, wildfly, wildfly-10

Currently, we have one application deployed in WildFly 10 ( Application_A ).

We use the system-property "log4j.configurationFile" in the standalone-full.xml to specify the location of the file containing log4j configuration.

```
<system-properties>
    <property name="log4j.configurationFile" value="file:C:/project/application_A/log4_apps_a.xml"/>
</system-properties>
```

We need to deploy another application ( Application_B) and would like to specify a log4j.xml file which has a different set of log4j configuration needed for Application_B.

However, our approach only allows us to specify one log4j.xml that would be applied to all applications deployed.

Is there an approach that would allow us to specify different log4j.xml for Application_A and Application_B ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Pete

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to include the `log4j.xml` in the deployment? Or just use the logging subsystem?

Comment: Hi James
Is there a reason you don't want to include the log4j.xml ?
Both Apps A and B are deployed as war files. Is your question, why the  log4j.xml  included in the war file. If so,  the reason is because we want to be able to change log levels with out the need to update/change the war file. External reference to the log4j.xml allows us to change the log level for the specific application ( A or B ) and to take effect, we just need to redeploy the war file ( restart WildFly )

If that is not the question, than I don't understand unfortunately.

Comment: Also not sure what you mean by "Or just use the logging subsystem?". Maybe you could clarify.

Thank you for replying.


Pete

Comment: Have a look at logging profiles http://docs.wildfly.org/Admin_Guide.html#logging-profiles. This allows you to use management interfaces to control logging.

Comment: Hi James

Thanks for the link. As with most things ( for me at least ), reading the techie notes only make sense with an example. I googled and came across following links :-

http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-log/using-a-logger-for-a-specific-application

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6.2/html/administration_and_configuration_guide/example_logging_profile_configuration

Comment: So my understanding, is that I can define in my standalone-full.xml two logging-profiles myappA and myappB:-

  <logging-profiles>  

    <logging-profile name="myappA">  
        ...........
    </logging-profile>  


    <logging-profile name="myappB">  
        ...........
    </logging-profile>  

  </logging-profiles>

I can associate the appropriate logging profile by including a Manifest file in the war file that specifies the logging-profile for the application eg

   Manifest-Version: 1.0
   Logging-Profile: myappA

Comment: log4j.xml for my application.
<code>
      <Configuration>
         <Appenders>
                 <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
          </Console>
          <RollingFile name="File" fileName="myappA.log"
           filePattern="myappA-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log">
          </RollingFile>
         </Appenders>
         <Loggers>
          <Logger name="com.src.myapp.test" level="debug" additivity="true">
              <AppenderRef ref="File" />
          </Logger>
          <Root level="debug">
          </Root>
         </Loggers>
      </Configuration>
</code>

Comment: Can i incorporate the above as is within the 
    <logging-profile name="myappA">  
        ...........
    </logging-profile>
Thank you for the helpful tips

Comment: Yes you can use a logging profile to allowing a different logging configuration for different deployments. I'd suggest using CLI or the web console vs editing the raw XML though.

Comment: Hi James
Not in a position to try the suggestions out. But just wanted to say thank you for your help. 
Pete

Comment: NP. The main issue is you can't have a system property defined twice. You're going to have to figure out an application specific way of getting the property. Maybe in the `web.xml` or something similar.